Google auth Client get token returns "invalid_grant"
When brand new users are coming to my website, they are redirected to google auth page then I use the code to send it to the server.
In some case the following code returns invalid_grant error.
const authClient = new OAuth2Client(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, GOOGLE_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL);

tokenResponse = await authClient.getToken(code);

Since it seems like they are brand new users, what can be the cause the token gets this error?
I did notice that on google developer console my oAuth rate limit is at max which doesn't make sense. according to my logs I'm WAY under the limit.
Should I refersh the secert key?
Update the concent page?
I
